# How to Input a token(int) and a 2d sequence in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, word-embedding

I am trying to train a model on input data which consists of a token (an id) and a 2d sequence data of fixed width(number of channels) and length(length of the time series window). I want the token to go to an embedding layer and the timeseries data to go to a LSTM later. My question is how do I input such a data in Keras/Tensorflow and then later inside the model how do I split it?

Comment: please let us know how you attempted to solve the problem (simple working code example)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer so posting it here. You can do it using the Lambda function provided by Keras.

```
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_)

x1= layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:,-1,-1])(x) 
x2 = layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,0:-1])(x)

y1 = layers.Embedding(100 ,16 ,input_length=1)(x1)
y2 = layers.LSTM(units=10, return_sequences=True)(x2)

y = layers.concatenate([y1,y2],axis=1)
y = layers.Flatten()(y)
```